# Android - Show Location button without showing native android location radius

Tags: android, google-maps, location

Well i have a map and i need to show the [Location Button](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener#public-methods) so i try this way:

```
 mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

And it works without any trouble, but in the ButtonListener i call a method to put a Marker on the actual location like this:

```
 mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
            setMarker();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I set the return true to disable the excecution of the super method but it still shows me the marker and the native location:

[image]

How can i only show the marker without hiding the Location Button?, i try this but it doesn't work.

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like it's not possible to use the standard "My Location" button and disable the default blue dot and circle, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110788/remove-default-users-location-icon

Comment: I don't think I ever tried it but this person claims to have a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31636469/3307720

Comment: @nasch i try to do that way and doesn't work, it's not possible to do like i want to do, thanks anyway

Comment: @DanielNugent It's true Daniel, it's not possible, thank you very much!